# NodeJS native mouse and keyboard bindings

Tags: node.js, macros, keyboard, mouse, native

I've been looking for a native nodejs module that supports mouse and keyboard listening and execution

i found this.. https://npmjs.org/package/mouse
but the source code looks like it only supports the browsers.

Comment: You're looking to capture mouse and keypress events in the terminal?

Comment: well if your saying listening for mouse movement in nodejs and then doing `console.log(mouse.x,mouse.y);` then yes

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: What environment are you trying to capture the input events from?  To get raw key events in node use http://nodejs.org/api/tty.html#tty_rs_setrawmode_mode.  But everything else is highly platform dependent.  Is this for linux, osx, windows, terminal, X11, Cocoa, etc?

Answer (score 12):

I've been working on a module for sending mouse and keyboard events, [RobotJS](https://github.com/octalmage/robotjs).

Example code:

```js
var robot = require("robotjs");

//Get the mouse position, retuns an object with x and y. 
var mouse=robot.getMousePos();
console.log("Mouse is at x:" + mouse.x + " y:" + mouse.y);

//Move the mouse down by 100 pixels.
robot.moveMouse(mouse.x,mouse.y+100);

//Left click!
robot.mouseClick();
```

Then for listening I use nw.js:

https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Shortcut

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap the [`Robot Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) provided by Java for a cross platform solution using the [`node-java`](https://github.com/joeferner/node-java) module.

Working example:

```js
var java = require('java');

var Robot = java.import('java.awt.Robot');
var robot = new Robot();

robot.mouseMoveSync(0, 0);
```

Comment: Did you ever test this to get it to work? On OSX Just tried it, it launches a Java Icon in the dock, but then does nothing, any ideas?

Comment: I tested it on Arch Linux using java version 1.7 (Oracle Java), node.js version 0.10.25, and the node-java module version 0.3.0.

Comment: @OwenMelbourne I don't work on the node-java project. You can try writing a simple Java program yourself that does this same thing and see if that works. If it does, you can  [open a new issue](https://github.com/joeferner/node-java/issues) on their project page with the code you used (both Java & Node.js code), operating system, version numbers, etc. and see if they can help you further.

Comment: If the above answer didn't work for you on OSX and you're just looking for simple mouse execution (no mouse listening) you might like this minimalistic wrapper https://github.com/Loknar/node-macmouse.
It uses the NodObjC module to hook into the Cocoa framework and send mouse commands to the system.

Answer (score 4):

Try [iohook](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iohook) module.
It support Windows/Linux/MacOS

```
'use strict';
const ioHook = require('iohook');

ioHook.on("mousemove", event => {
   console.log(event);
   /* You get object like this
   {
      type: 'mousemove',
      x: 700,
      y: 400
    }
   */
});
// For keyboard hook
ioHook.on("keydown", event => { .... });
ioHook.on("keyup", event => { .... });

//Register and start hook 
ioHook.start();
```

Comment: I get only one keydown event. I use Node v6.11.1.

Comment: Please review https://github.com/wilix-team/iohook. It contains many information about module/configs and etc.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://github.com/Loknar/node-macmouse

$ npm install macmouse

## example.js

var mouse = require('macmouse');

```
mouse.init();

var ptX = 800;
var ptY = 600;

var doThings = function() {
    mouse.Place(ptX, ptY);
    setTimeout(pressAndHold, 250);
}

var pressAndHold = function() {
    mouse.LeftButtonPress();
    setTimeout(doDragStuff, 250);
}

var doDragStuff = function() {
    ptX += 2;
    ptY += 2;
    mouse.DragPlace(ptX, ptY);
    setTimeout(doDragStuff, 250);
}

doThings();

mouse.quit();
```