# Move mouse cursor with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mouse

Is there is any way or module to move cursor and simulate mouse clicks in windows7/8 with node.js?

I found this library https://www.npmjs.org/package/win_mouse but seems like it doesn't work

Comment: If you have Java on your system, you can use Java + node as my answer here describes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21080830/586621

Comment: What do you mean by "seems like it doesn't work"? Are there errors?

Comment: @RalphWiggum Yes, when I'm trying to run my js file through prompt, I'm getting this error:
module.js:356
Module._extensions[extension](this, filename);
Error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Comment: @TrevorSenior I tried your solution, but I'm getting this error: Error: Error creating class
java.lang.InternalError: Can't start the AWT because Java was started on the first thread.  Make sure StartOnFirstThread is not specified in your application's Info.plist or on the command line

Comment: let's take a moment to acknowledge that almost everyone  came here because they want to create a simple mouse juggler, to continue appearing online on Microsoft Teams or other while they are away slacking during home office.

Answer (score 45):

I've been working on a module for this, [RobotJS](https://github.com/octalmage/robotjs).

Example code:

```js
var robot = require("robotjs");

//Get the mouse position, retuns an object with x and y. 
var mouse=robot.getMousePos();
console.log("Mouse is at x:" + mouse.x + " y:" + mouse.y);

//Move the mouse down by 100 pixels.
robot.moveMouse(mouse.x,mouse.y+100);

//Left click!
robot.mouseClick();
```

It's still a work in progress but it will do what you want!

Comment: It seems exactly what I want, too bad I need to run this on a Windows machine though.. I keep getting errors when I try to install it

Comment: The library will support Windows soon!

Comment: There is now a Windows build, see this issue: https://github.com/octalmage/robotjs/issues/2

Comment: A neat  module you've got there. I am planning to  use this with my bluetooth IMU as it already is on node.

Comment: Its awesome. good module and very useful.

Comment: RobotJS doesn't seem to work with new versions of node. Had to use node version < 9 in order to get it to work.

Comment: Yeah, doesn't work for me either, I keep getting all sorts of errors

Answer (score 8):

I've previously tried the `win_mouse` package, but it didn't work for me either, think it requires an older version of node.js.

One solution would be to use the [ffi](https://www.npmjs.org/package/ffi) package, which allows you to dynamically load and call native libraries.  To move the mouse on windows, you'd need to call the `SetCursorPos` function from the `user32.dll` like this:

```
var ffi = require("ffi");

var user32 = ffi.Library('user32', {
    'SetCursorPos': [ 'long', ['long', 'long'] ]
    // put other functions that you want to use from the library here, e.g., "GetCursorPos"
});

var result = user32.SetCursorPos(10, 10);
console.log(result);
```

Another solution would be to write a [native node add-on](http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) that wraps around the `SetCursorPos` function, but it is more complex.

Comment: +1 but how would you define GetCursorPos, given that the method requires a pointer to a `Point`? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648390%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Follow this guide: https://github.com/node-ffi/node-ffi/wiki/Node-FFI-Tutorial Specifically, the section on `Structs` at the bottom.