# Change position cursor in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it possible to use node js to control the cursor?
Or should I write a module for this?

Change the position and click the left or right mouse button.

Comment: I don't think that's possible at all using only JavaScript :/

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22695122/move-mouse-cursor-with-node-js - I'm flagging this as a duplicate to link it to the other question.